Cannot read properties of undefined when image in chat messages
I have this javascript that reads chats from Google Chat export. When there is a picture attached in a chat I get  typeError:
TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'File-foobar.png')
at convertImageFilename (google_chat_takeout_reader.html:173:58)
at preprocessImages (google_chat_takeout_reader.html:268:37)
at readAndDisplayJsonFile (google_chat_takeout_reader.html:372:44)

Full code here:


const chatMetadataEntries = {};
const chatMessageFiles = {};
const fileCache = {};
const imgCache = {};
const chatMessageCache = {};

const extensionRegex = /\.[0-9a-z]+$/i;

async function addChatMetadataEntry(itemPath, entry) {
  const file = await entry.getFile();
  const text = await file.text();
  const json = JSON.parse(text);

  const chatId = getDirectoryName(itemPath);
  chatMetadataEntries[chatId] = {
    members: json.members
  };
  if ("name" in json) {
    chatMetadataEntries[chatId].name = json.name;
  }

  // set up imgCache for this chatId
  imgCache[chatId] = {};
}

function escapeFilename(filename) {
  if (!extensionRegex.test(filename)) {
    // default to jpg. some extensions are missing in messagess.json
    // but the files exported have .jpg ext
    console.log("image file before escapeFilename: ", filename);
    filename += ".jpg";
    console.log("image file After escapeFilename: ", filename);
  }
  return filename.replace(/[\?:]/g, '_');
}

function convertImageFilename(chatId, filename) {
  console.log("image file before escapeFilename: ", filename);
  let imgFile = escapeFilename(filename);
  console.log("image file After escapeFilename: ", imgFile);
  console.log("imgCache file before : ", imgCache);
  imgCache[chatId][imgFile] = (imgCache[chatId][imgFile] || 0) + 1;

  if (imgCache[chatId][imgFile] > 1) {
    let imgIdx = imgCache[chatId][imgFile] - 1;
    let imgExt = imgFile.substring(imgFile.lastIndexOf('.'));
    let imgBase = imgFile.substring(0, imgFile.lastIndexOf('.'));
    imgFile = `${imgBase}(${imgIdx})${imgExt}`;
  }

  return imgFile;
}

function getDirectoryName(filePath) {
  const parts = filePath.split('/');

  // Return the second-to-last element
  if (parts.length < 2) {
    return ".";
  }

  return parts[parts.length - 2].replace(/\s/g, "-");
}

function addChatMessagesEntry(itemPath, entry) {
  const chatId = getDirectoryName(itemPath);
  chatMessageFiles[chatId] = entry;
}

function formatTimestamp(timestamp) {
  if (timestamp == undefined) {
    return "";
  }

  // Format is "Thursday, July 14, 2016 at 5:04:34 PM UTC"
  timestamp = timestamp.replace(' at ', ' ')
  const date = new Date(timestamp);
  return date.toLocaleString();
}

async function addToFileCache(itemPath, entry) {
  const chatId = getDirectoryName(itemPath);

  // initialize fileCache for this chatId
  if (!(chatId in fileCache)) {
    fileCache[chatId] = {};
  }

  file = await entry.getFile();
  fileCache[chatId][entry.name] = file;
}

function getImgSrcPath(chatId, filename) {
  const file = fileCache[chatId][filename];
  try {
    return URL.createObjectURL(file);
  } catch (e) {
    console.error(e);
    return "";
  }
}

function getChatMembersTitle(chatId) {
  if (chatMetadataEntries[chatId] == undefined) {
    // TODO what the hell?
    return "unknown";
  }

  if ("name" in chatMetadataEntries[chatId]) {
    return chatMetadataEntries[chatId].name;
  }

  return getChatMembers(chatId).join(" • ");
}

function getChatMembers(chatId) {
  if (chatMetadataEntries[chatId] == undefined) {
    // TODO what the hell?
    return [];
  }

  return chatMetadataEntries[chatId].members.map(member => member.name);
}


function showOptsForm(chatId) {
  $('#opts-' + chatId).toggle();
}

function preprocessImages(chatId, msgsJson) {
  for (const msg of msgsJson.messages) {
    if (!("attached_files" in msg)) {
      continue;
    }
    for (const file of msg.attached_files) {
      console.log("image file before: ", file);
      const imgFile = convertImageFilename(chatId, file.export_name);
      console.log("converted filename: ", imgFile);
      file.export_name = imgFile;
    }
  }

  return msgsJson;
}

async function showChatList() {
  await pickDirectory();
  console.log("Chats loaded")

  const chatList = $('#chatList');

  if (Object.keys(chatMessageFiles).length == 0) {
    chatList.append(`<br><i>No chats found</i>`);
    return;
  }

  chatList.empty();
  chatList.append($('<h6 class="mt-3">Select chat to view</h6>'));
  for (const chatId in chatMessageFiles) {
    const listItem = $('<li class="list-group-item"></li>').html(`<a href="#" onclick="readAndDisplayJsonFile('${chatId}')">${getChatMembersTitle(chatId)}</a> <span class="show-opts badge"><a href="#" onclick="showOptsForm('${chatId}')">opts</a></span>`);
    const formDiv = $(`<div class="chat-opts" id="opts-${chatId}"></div`);
    const formItem = $(`<form id="opts-form-${chatId}" onsubmit="readAndDisplayJsonFile('${chatId}')"></form>`);
    formItem.append(`
                            <input type="checkbox" id="imagesOnly-${chatId}" name="imagesOnly" class="form-check-input">
                            <label for="imagesOnly">Images Only</label>`);
    for (const member of getChatMembers(chatId)) {
      formItem.append(`
                            <br>
                            <input type="checkbox" data-exclude-name="${member}" name="exclude" class="form-check-input">
                            <label for="exclude">Hide ${member} messages</label>`);
    }
    formDiv.append(formItem);
    formDiv.append(`<button class="opts-btn btn btn-secondary btn-sm" onclick="readAndDisplayJsonFile('${chatId}')"">Apply</button>`)
    listItem.append(formDiv);
    chatList.append(listItem);
  }
}

async function pickDirectory() {
  const chatList = $('#chatList');
  try {
    const directoryHandle = await window.showDirectoryPicker({
      startIn: "downloads"
    });
    $('#chat').empty();
    $('#chat_header').hide();
    chatList.html(`<i>Loading chats...</i>`);
    await listFilesRecursive(directoryHandle, chatList);
  } catch (err) {
    console.error(`Error: ${err}`);
    chatList.html(`<i>Error: ${err.message}</i>`);
  }
}

async function listFilesRecursive(directoryHandle, chatList, prefix = '') {
  console.log("Looking for chats in ", directoryHandle.name);
  for await (const entry of directoryHandle.values()) {
    const itemPath = `${prefix}${entry.name}`;
    // console.log("processing ", itemPath);
    if (entry.kind === 'file') {
      if (entry.name.endsWith('messages.json')) {
        addChatMessagesEntry(itemPath, entry);
      } else if (entry.name.endsWith('group_info.json')) {
        addChatMetadataEntry(itemPath, entry);
      } else {
        await addToFileCache(itemPath, entry);
      }
    } else if (entry.kind === 'directory') {
      if (entry.name.startsWith('.') || entry.name === 'Users') {
        continue;
      }
      await listFilesRecursive(entry, chatList, itemPath + '/');
    }
  }
}

async function goToMessage(chatId) {
  const messageNum = $(`#goToMessage`).val().replace(/,/g, '');
  let i = parseInt(messageNum);

  if (isNaN(i)) {
    alert("Unfortunately not a number: " + messageNum);
    return;
  } else if (i < 1) {
    i = 0;
  }

  await readAndDisplayJsonFile(chatId, {
    start: i - 1
  });
}

async function readAndDisplayJsonFile(chatId, opts = {}) {
  if (!(chatId in chatMessageCache)) {
    console.log(`Reading and parsing ${chatId} messages.json`);
    const entry = chatMessageFiles[chatId];
    $('#chat_header').text(getChatMembersTitle(chatId));
    $('#chat_header').show();

    const chatBox = $('#chat');
    chatBox.html('<i>Loading messages...</i>');

    const file = await entry.getFile();
    const text = await file.text();
    chatMessageCache[chatId] = preprocessImages(chatId, JSON.parse(text));
  }

  window.scrollTo(0, 0);
  const chatBox = $('#chat');
  chatBox.empty();

  const json = chatMessageCache[chatId];
  const max = Math.min(5000, json.messages.length);

  const imagesOnly = $('#imagesOnly-' + chatId).is(':checked');

  let excludeSenders = {};
  for (const member of getChatMembers(chatId)) {
    if ($(`#opts-form-${chatId} input[data-exclude-name="${member}"]`).is(':checked')) {
      excludeSenders[member] = true;
    }
  }

  let start = ("start" in opts) ? opts.start : 0;

  if (start >= json.messages.length) {
    start = json.messages.length - max;
  }

  const end = Math.min(start + max, json.messages.length);

  console.log(`Displaying ${max} messages from ${start} to ${json.messages.length}`);
  for (let i = start; i < end; i++) {
    const nextNav = $(`<a href="#" onclick="readAndDisplayJsonFile('${chatId}', {start: ${end} })">Next starting at ${(end + 1).toLocaleString("en")} of ${json.messages.length.toLocaleString("en")}</a>`);

    if (json.messages.length > max && i === start) {
      const navItem = $('<div class="nav top small"></div>');
      navItem.append(`Showing messages ${(start + 1).toLocaleString("en")} to ${end.toLocaleString("en")} of ${json.messages.length.toLocaleString("en")}`);

      if (start > 0) {
        navItem.append(` | <a href="#" onclick="readAndDisplayJsonFile('${chatId}', {start: ${Math.max(0, start - max)} })">Previous ${max.toLocaleString("en")} of ${json.messages.length.toLocaleString("en")}</a></b>`);
      }

      if (end + 1 < json.messages.length) {
        navItem.append(" | ");
        navItem.append(nextNav);
      }

      navItem.append(` | <div class="jump-to-msg">Jump to message <input type="text" size=4 id="goToMessage">`);
      navItem.append(`<button class="btn-secondary btn-sm" onclick="goToMessage('${chatId}')">Go</button></div>`);
      chatBox.append(navItem);

      $("#goToMessage").on('keyup', function(e) {
        if (e.key === 'Enter' || e.keyCode === 13) {
          goToMessage(chatId);
        }
      });
    }

    if (json.messages[i].creator.name in excludeSenders) {
      continue;
    }
    if (imagesOnly && !("attached_files" in json.messages[i])) {
      continue;
    }

    let message = `<b>${json.messages[i].creator.name}</b> ${formatTimestamp(json.messages[i].created_date)}<br>`;
    if ("text" in json.messages[i]) {
      message += `${json.messages[i].text}<br>`;
    }
    if ("attached_files" in json.messages[i]) {
      for (const file of json.messages[i].attached_files) {
        // console.log("showing file: ", file);
        const imgSrc = getImgSrcPath(chatId, file.export_name);
        message += `<a href="${imgSrc}" target="_blank"><img src="${imgSrc}" class="thumbnail"></a><br>`;
      }
    }
    if ("reactions" in json.messages[i]) {
      message += `<div class="reactions">`;
      for (const reaction of json.messages[i].reactions) {
        message += `<p title="${reaction.reactor_emails}">${reaction.emoji.unicode}</p>`;
      }
      message += `</div><br>`;
    }

    message += `<br>`;

    chatBox.append(message);

    if (end < json.messages.length && i === end - 1) {
      const navItem = $('<div class="nav small"></div>');
      navItem.append(nextNav);
      chatBox.append(navItem);
    }
  }
}

$(document).ready(function() {
  $('#select-directory').click(showChatList);
});
body {
  padding-top: 20px;
}

h1.page_header {
  display: block;
  padding: 20px;
  margin-bottom: 20px;
  background-color: #ccc;
  vertical-align: middle;
  line-height: 60px;
}

h1.page_header img {
  max-width: 60px;
  max-height: 60px;
  float: right;
}

#chatList {
  font-size: 12pt;
}

#chatList li:hover {
  background-color: #f0f0f0;
}

.show-opts {
  font-size: 8pt;
  font-weight: normal;
  background-color: #fefefe;
  display: inline-block;
}

.show-opts a {
  text-decoration: none;
}

.show-opts a:hover {
  text-decoration: underline;
}

.chat-opts {
  font-size: 10pt;
  background-color: #ccc;
  display: none;
  margin-top: 5px;
  padding: 10px;
}

.chat-opts form .form-check-input {
  vertical-align: top;
}

.jump-to-msg {
  display: inline-block;
  vertical-align: top;
}

.jump-to-msg button {
  font-size: 9pt;
  line-height: 16px;
}

.jump-to-msg input {
  vertical-align: top;
  font-size: 9pt;
  width: 70px;
}

.opts-btn {
  margin-top: 5px;
  font-size: 8pt;
  padding: .25rem;
}

#chat_header {
  background-color: #198754;
  color: #fff;
  display: none;
  padding: 10px;
  //border-radius: 5px;
  margin-bottom: 10px;
}

#chat {
  white-space: pre-wrap;
  padding: 10px;
  font-size: 11pt;
  border: 1px solid #000;
  margin-bottom: 30px;
}

#chat img.thumbnail {
  max-width: 40%;
}

#chat div.reactions {
  background-color: #efefef;
  display: inline-block;
  margin-left: 3pt;
}

#chat div.reactions p {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 3pt 3pt 0 3pt;
  display: inline-block;
}

.nav {
  padding: 6pt;
  background-color: #ececec;
}

.nav.top {
  margin-bottom: 10pt;
}
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.3.0/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">

<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.6.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<!-- Bootstrap Bundle with Popper -->
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.3.0/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js"></script>

<div class="container">
  <div class="row header_container">
    <h1 class="page_header">Google Takeout | Google Chat Reader
      <img src="https://github.com/mrwoof/google-chat-takeout-reader/blob/main/static/img/chat-reader-logo.png?raw=true" alt="Chat Reader">
    </h1>
  </div>
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-3">
      <button id="select-directory" class="btn btn-success btn-sm">Select Takeout Directory</button>
      <ul id="chatList" class="list-group mt-3"><i>Choose the directory of uncompressed Takeout files</i></ul>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-8">
      <h5 id="chat_header"></h5>
      <div id="chat" class="border rounded"></div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>



I can't understand why is says undefined. I print to console and see the name of the file.
The folder that I'm selecting includes a .json and a .png:

messages.json
File-foobar.png

This is the 'messages.json':


{
    "messages": [
      {
        "creator": {
          "name": "Foo Bar",
          "email": "foo@bar.com",
          "user_type": "Human"
        },
        "created_date": "Wednesday 12 October 1896 at 08:42:04 UTC",
        "text": "The foo bar is strong!",
        "topic_id": "K1Aq5fV9y1E",
        "message_id": "-MdQTIAAAAE/K1Aq5fV9y1E/K1Aq5fV9y1E"
      },
      {
        "creator": {
          "name": "Darth Jedi",
          "email": "darth@jedi.com",
          "user_type": "Human"
        },
        "created_date": "Wednesday 12 October 1896 at 08:44:24 UTC",
        "text": "Not as strong as this.  ",
        "topic_id": "zg4G2ovznXM",
        "message_id": "-MdQTIAAAAE/zg4G2ovznXM/zg4G2ovznXM"
      },
      {
        "creator": {
          "name": "Foo Bar",
          "email": "foo@bar.com",
          "user_type": "Human"
        },
        "created_date": "Wednesday 12 October 1896 at 08:44:53 UTC",
        "text": "",
        "topic_id": "rT-qN6cLzbk",
        "message_id": "-MdQTIAAAAE/rT-qN6cLzbk/rT-qN6cLzbk"
      },
      {
        "creator": {
          "name": "Darth Jedi",
          "email": "darth@jedi.com",
          "user_type": "Human"
        },
        "created_date": "Wednesday 12 October 1896 at 08:47:08 UTC",
        "attached_files": [
          {
            "original_name": "foobar.png",
            "export_name": "File-foobar.png"
          }
        ],
        "topic_id": "h8DDIAHI848",
        "message_id": "-MdQTIAAAAE/h8DDIAHI848/h8DDIAHI848"
      }
    ]
  }




the error is in imgCache[chatId][imgFile] = (imgCache[chatId][imgFile] || 0) + 1; .... at a guess, imgCache[chatId] is undefined
